# How to find difference between two dates which is in string format in android

Tags: android, datetime

```
Calendar zCalendarL = Calendar.getInstance(); 
SimpleDateFormat zDateFormatL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

String DateTime="2013/02/15 15:05:01";
String zUpdatedDateTimeG =zDateFormatL.format(DateTime);

String zCurrentDateTimeL=zDateFormatL.format(zCalendarL.getTime());
```

I need to know the date time between zCurrentDateTimeL and zUpdatedDateTimeG

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
I hope this will be help to you this is worked for me...

```
        private void getDifference(java.util.Date startTime,
            java.util.Date endTime, java.util.Date eartime,
            java.util.Date curtime) {

        Calendar startDateTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                .getTimeZone("GMT-5:00"));
        startDateTime.setTime(startTime);
        Calendar endDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDateTime.setTime(endTime);           
        long milliseconds1 = startDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
        long milliseconds2 = endDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
        long diff = Math.abs(milliseconds1 - milliseconds2);
        long seconds = diff / (1000);

              }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar zCalendarL = Calendar.getInstance(); 
SimpleDateFormat zDateFormatL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

String DateTime="2013/02/15 15:05:01";

Date d = zDateFormatL.parse(DateTime);
long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - d.getTime();
```

this will return the difference in miliseconds